# How to get a template list from several clusters?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to migrate from a 6.0 vCenter to a 6.5 vCenter, and want to migrate all templates. How can I select all clusters at once to retrieve the full template list?

I have a lot of templates in my 6.0 vCenter and need to export a list to migrate them all at once in my new 6.5 vCenter, using Powercli. The only way I found is by using a foreach loop, in which I must provide a cluster name.
I tried using "get-datacenter" instead of "get-cluster" but the result is even worse.

```
$toto = foreach ($vmhost in Get-Cluster 'my_cluster'|Get-VMHost) {
    Get-Template -Location $vmhost |
        select name, @{n='VMHOST';e={$vmhost.name}},
            @{n='VMTX';e={$_.extensiondata.config.files.VmPathName}}
} 

$toto | Export-Csv C:\scripts\Templates.csv
```

The code works but doesn't show me all templates in the vCenter.
How can I make it work so that I can have all templates in all clusters at once, without using a loop for each?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the result is even worse" when passing a `Datacenter` instance to `Get-Cluster`?  Have you tried passing a `Datacenter` as the `-Location` parameter of `Get-Template`, as shown in the example in [the documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-Template.html)?

Comment: I did try `Get-Template -Location DatacenterName | Select-Object Name,DatastoreIdList` but the issue was that `DatastoreIdList` returned a table. I didn't try with the `foreach` line shown before. And yes, it worked... Thank you

Comment: Pipe format-list work?

Answer (score 0):

The function extracts all templates from a single datacenter target by scanning all available clusters and hosts within; dumping the complete result into an $array_list variable.

Function Render_Template_List {

```
Clear-Host
$array_list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
if (!($global:templates_bool)) {
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Retrieving available templates for use with '$global:datacenter' datacenter...Please Wait!"
    if ($global:datacenter -eq 'none'){
        $ESX = get-datacenter | get-VMhost | %{$_.Extensiondata.MoRef}
    } else {
        $ESX = get-datacenter -name "$global:datacenter" | get-VMhost | %{$_.Extensiondata.MoRef}
    }
    If ($global:Template -eq 'none') {
        $Query = Get-Template | where {$ESX -contains $_.Extensiondata.Runtime.Host} | Sort-Object               
    } else {
        $Query = Get-Template -name "$global:Template" | where {$ESX -contains $_.Extensiondata.Runtime.Host} | Sort-Object        
    }
    $global:templates_bool = $true
    $global:templates_query = $query

} 
$seperator = "{,}"
$query = 0
$arr = 1
foreach ($template in $global:templates_query )  {
    if ($arr -eq 1) {
        foreach ($array in $global:templates_array) {
            If (!($array -like "*#*")) {
                $query = $query + 1
                $val_template = $array.split($seperator)[2]
                $val_template = $val_template.replace("`"","") 
                if ("$val_template" -eq "$template") {
                    $val_datacenter = $array.split($seperator)[1]
                    $val_datacenter = $val_datacenter.replace("`"","")                    
                    if ("$val_datacenter" -eq "$global:datacenter")  {
                        $array_list.Add("$val_template") | Out-Null
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }     
    if ($query -eq 0) {
        $array_list.Add("$template") | Out-Null
        $arr = 0
    }
}     

return $array_list
```

}